# Ultrasonic transducers driver review (25 kHz, 150 Vp-p)

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation, transducer

**Transducers specs:**

- Resonance frequency = 25 kHz +/-1 kHz
- Maximum driving voltage = 150 Vp-p
- Capacitance = 2.4 nF +/-20%

**Proposed driver circuit and simulation:**

Seven transducers are driven for a total capacitance of 16.8nF (C1 below) using a parallel LC resonant circuit controlled by 25 kHz, 5 V 50% PWM signal (V1) from an Arduino. [This is the inductor](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata/22R225C?qs=sGAEpiMZZMthaSLPVp%252B4anIT9HmvpezV) used with a maximum resistance of 8.58 ohms that is added to the model. The simulation is also shown for "Vout", "Vc" and "Vpwm".

[image]

**Implementation and measurements:**

I get the waveform below from the real circuit. Amplitude is 108 Vpp which is acceptable and could increase by increasing the input voltage (V2). Frequency is 25 kHz which is correct.

However, duty cycle seems to be the issue. The waveform just does not fill the entire 25 kHz period same as in the simulation. I wonder what could be wrong with the implementation or the simulation to cause this issue?

[image]

Comment: D1 is toast (if it's really a 1N4148)

Comment: @user_1818839 It is a 1N4148. From the simulation, I can see the current through it peaks at 150mA for very short bursts. And the reverse voltage is 0-70V which is still below 75V max peak. May be I'm missing something

Comment: Well, maybe not *dark* toast then...

Comment: Do you think I should try with another diode?

Comment: Well I don't think it's the main problem, I just think it's being run closer to its limits than I like. If you try another diode though, it must eb a fast recovery diode (not a 1N4005!)

Answer (score 2):

There is a frequency mismatch between the 25 kHz PWM drive frequency and the resonance frequency of L1/C1, which I estimate from the screen shot to be around 40 kHz.
The polarity change comes long before the transistor is turned on.

In this simulation I changed the inductor to 1 mH to increase the tank resonance frequency. The result looks like the same wrong waveform.

This NE555 circuit is just used to create a variable duty cycle square wave in the simulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiYG3Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>